# How could I set the value on selecting without clicking apply button

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I want to change the value when user selecting the daterange,

If the user leave the popup window and forget to click apply button,

The value should be saved without losing.

How could I do that, thanks~

## javascript

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var days_of_week =$.parseJSON('#{escape_javascript(t('date.abbr_day_names').to_json)}');
    $('#date-range-picker').daterangepicker(
      {
        locale: {
          daysOfWeek: days_of_week,
          applyLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.apply')}",
          cancelLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.cancel')}",
          fromLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.depart_date')}",
          toLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.return_date')}",
        },
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        dateLimit: { days: 30 }
      },
      function(start, end, label) {
        console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
      }
    );
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try change() method

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp

The change event occurs when the value of an element is changed (only works on form fields).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an option to pass in for onSelect like jQuery ui's date picker has http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect (which I also recommend using) but I can show you a hacky example to make it work if you're set on using the daterangepicker.

```
// when a start date is clicked
$('.calendar.left .available').click(function(e) {

  // get the changed date from the input field on the calendar
  var selectedStartDate = $('[name="daterangepicker_start"]').val();

  // get current range to modify
  var currentRange = $('[name="daterange"]').val();

  // set new range value
  $('[name="daterange"]').val(rangeFromNewStart(selectedStartDate, currentRange);

  // close the dialog
  $('.daterangepicker').css('display', 'none');
});

function rangeFromNewStart(startValue, currentRange){
  startValue + ' -' + currentRange.split('-')[1];
};
```

However as I said earlier, you have more flexibility with jQuery ui. In addition to this this is again a hacky approach to a simple problem. If you notice, in this example I only showed you how to change the start date. You would have to reproduce this functionality with the right calendar if you wanted to modify the end date.